# android deploymant build failure in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, deployment, sdk

Error:C:\Users\Tenchoo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools is not a directory. calculated from system property com.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: You should check "how to ask question?"

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you unity versión its imcompatible whith new SDK uptates, i make it build:using 
1. "target jelly bean 4.4" in unity player/settings
2. Download and install http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip unzip and replace your tools directory inside your sdk folder
3. Optional download and reinstall your JAVA (im not shure its)https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-windows-x64.exe?AuthParam=1582981391_9802e885b21f6811e6cb6278b75ea411
pick "jdk-8u131-windows-x64.exe"

none other google solutions worked for me, all of this is not consider a solution because i'm need to compile for android 5.0 too, i will update my unity and try again if this work